# Why was the analog clock popularity-contest question deleted?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

Why was [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20377/analogue-clock-with-any-language) deleted? For those who can't see it, its title was "Analogue Clock with any language".

It was closed as a duplicate, but it happens that it is not a duplicate. The question linked as a duplicate was tagged with [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), but this one was tagged with [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest).

The first close-voter, David Carraher, posted this comment there:

> squeamish ossifrage, Your comment has made me reconsider my vote to close. I also see that the earlier question required ASCII art; this one does not. Is there a way to nullify my vote to close?

As a result, it was being reopened, and already had 3 votes for reopen (including mine), but then  the Community♦ moderator deleted it.

I think that it was actually a good question that was unluckly downvoted and not well-understood. It should not be closed, and much less be deleted. It already had one promising nice answer, and I am writing another answer too (I was sure that it would eventually be reopened).

So could that question be undeleted? If not, can I repost it?

Comment: Community is literally the dumbest moderator here. Unfortunately, it's still a moderator and its delete votes cannot be overriden by us mere mortals.

Comment: Flagged for undeletion. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer because I'm only guessing, but my guess is that it was deleted because the user account that created it was deleted (see recent meta posts). As to undeleting it: I disagree that it was a good question. A good question sets clear boundaries against which submissions can be judged. I have yet to see a single good question which was two sentences long. I think it would be preferable for you to write a better specified version, run it through the sandbox, and then post that.

Comment: @Victor Go for it. It looks like user 16137 doesn't exist any more, so there's no chance of this question being undeleted.

Comment: The question was asked by a sockpuppet account. Perhaps someone could open a new question based on the same idea. Maybe spec it out a little better though.

Comment: @gnibbler OP has already gone ahead. Please check his answer here

Comment: I posted a new question: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20646/create-an-analogue-clock-popularity-contest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user who posted the question was deleted because they were a sockpuppet of [Utkarsh Asian Verma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16123/utkarsh-asian-verma). The user posted several low-quality questions, posted low-quality answers to them as his “real” account, and then marked those answers as accepted.

Therefore, I’d surmise that the *question* was deleted because its whole purpose was this sockpuppetry; but I’m not sure because [another question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/20379/668) that had the same purpose didn’t get deleted (possibly because several users posted legitimate answers), although Utkarsh Asian Verma’s answer did get deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The question got reopened, but not undeleted. This is a really weird situation.

As suggested by Peter Taylor (and incentived by squeamish ossifrage), it is unlikely that the old question can be revived because the OP had its account deleted. So, I posted a revival proposal in the sandbox: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/974/3755

In the unlikelly case that the question eventually get to be undeleted anyway, I will edit it with the text I posted in the sandbox (except, of course, if somebody else does that first), to ensure that it is better worded.

EDIT: New question posted: [Create an analogue clock](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20646/create-an-analogue-clock-popularity-contest)